# nmap doesn't give service versions using -sV

Tags: nmap

Running the command

```
nmap -sV -T4 -A x.x.x.x
```

results in

```
5901/tcp  open  ssl/vnc-1?
|_ssl-date: TLS randomness does not represent time
| fingerprint-strings: 
|   GetRequest: 
|     HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
|     Content-Type: text/html
|     Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
|     Connection: close
|     Content-Length: 689
|     X-Iinfo: 11-59405098-0 0NNN RT(1671532084348 45) q(0 -1 -1 -1) r(0 -1)
|     <html style="height:100%"><head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"></head><body style="margin:0px;height:100%"><iframe id="main-iframe" src="/_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=27&xinfo=11-59405098-0%200NNN%20RT%281671532084348%2045%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%20-1%29%20r%280%20-1%29&incident_id=0-293333587589927179&edet=9&cinfo=ffffffff&rpinfo=0&mth=GET" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 0-293333587589927179</iframe></body></html>
|   HTTPOptions: 
|     HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
|     Content-Type: text/html
|     Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
|     Connection: close
|     Content-Length: 693
|     X-Iinfo: 12-85814171-0 0NNN RT(1671532084436 46) q(0 -1 -1 -1) r(0 -1)
|_    <html style="height:100%"><head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"></head><body style="margin:0px;height:100%"><iframe id="main-iframe" src="/_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=27&xinfo=12-85814171-0%200NNN%20RT%281671532084436%2046%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%20-1%29%20r%280%20-1%29&incident_id=0-428677047993045260&edet=9&cinfo=ffffffff&rpinfo=0&mth=OPTIONS" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 0-428677047993045260</iframe></body></html
| tls-nextprotoneg: 
|_  http/1.1
******************************************* sensored
| Not valid before: 2022-07-27T08:54:39
|_Not valid after:  2023-01-23T08:54:36
```

the result above is only for port 5901
the whole scan is too long

but won't show which version is being used.

How can I get the version? and what should I do next if I have no versions of services that are being used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put, your target is not obliged to provide you with the version number and that is what's happening here. You cannot force a target to give you a version number if it does not divulge it in a banner or give any hints to as what the version number is. Obviously if you have access to the target machine you can check what's installed on it.

The likely reason why `nmap` is failing is because your target is behind an Imperva Web Application Firewall. It's likely determining that it's not a valid VNC connect attempt (or is it a VNC server at all? we don't know) and returning an HTTP 503 error. The WAF is doing its job.

If this is a pentesting task determine if it's an actual VNC server by trying to connect to it and take it from there by trying out exploits for vulnerable versions and testing misconfigurations. If it's part of an asset management exercise, simply ask your sysadmins.

Answer (score 0):

From [Nmap official documentation](https://nmap.org/book/man-version-detection.html):

> After TCP and/or UDP ports are discovered using one of the other scan methods, version detection interrogates those ports to determine more about what is actually running. The nmap-service-probes database contains probes for querying various services and match expressions to recognize and parse responses. Nmap tries to determine the service protocol [...], the application name [...], the version number, hostname, device type [...], the OS family.

However:

> Of course, most services don't provide all of this information.

### Tl;Dr

The service you're scanning might not disclose its version when being probed by Nmap.

You can try using the flag `-sC` to run Nmap with the most common scripts, or use `--script vnc-info` to specifically run the `vnc-info` script.

More infos about how to run scripts with Nmap [here](https://nmap.org/book/nse-usage.html).

Comment: That's why I asked for the full output. VNC should output a version banner. But we need more info.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to comment my "answer" underneath the original question to avoid posting such a light answer, but I do not have enough reputation to do so. So instead of saying nothing I posted it with some ideas, hoping it would help

Comment: tried vnc-info , won't give much. there is only one port that gives information and its https IIS verison 8.5. there are many other ports , like 100 or even more (ms-sql, other vnc, smtp, ftp,pop3,ms-lsa..... ALOT) every port's scan results in similar as posted.

Comment: The scan is being blocked by Imperva